# Error while deleting stateless service in Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

In Service Fabric Cluster i have a stateless service which has a while(true) loop running continuously in RunAsync Method. Due to this while loop i am finding it hard to delete the application from the cluster. Error occurs every time i try to delete stating cannot detach the process.Normally i try to deploy the application once to remove the code. To redeploy the code on top of the application i have to deploy twice. Is there a work around to this without removing the infinite while loop.

Updated: Runasync Method

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //making sure the thread is active 
        while (true)
        {
           do something;
        }

    }
```

Thank you for the input.

Comment: Can you add your RunAsync method here for better understanding?

Comment: I have added the Runasync Method .

Answer (score 3):

During shutdown, the cancellation token passed to RunAsync is canceled.
You need to check the cancellation token's IsCancellationRequested property in your main loop. When this becomes true, and if called, the token's ThrowIfCancellationRequested method throws an OperationCanceledException.

If your service does not respond to these API calls in a reasonable amount of time, Service Fabric can forcibly terminate your service. Usually this only happens during application upgrades or when a service is being deleted. This timeout is 15 minutes by default.

See this document for a good reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-lifecycle#stateless-service-shutdown